# How to shutdown JVM if one thread crashes in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I have a Java program which on a high level looks like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    Thread t1 = new ComplicatedThread1();
    Thread t2 = new ComplicatedThread2();
    Thread t3 = new ComplicatedThread3();

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();

}
```

Each of the threads contain a lot of code which is not written by me.
There might be several **sub-threads** within one thread.
The biggest problem occurs if **exactly one** thread crashes (i.e. throws an uncaught runtime exception). In that case the whole program is still running, but it
is malfunctioning.

Now given that I am not capable of making each of the threads foolproof, I would like to shut down JVM completely whenever **any** thread crashes.

**Question**: how to catch runtime exception in the main program raised by **any** thread and ask the system to shutdown?

Answer (score 6):

Add a few lines at the top of your main procedure:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // Making sure that if one thread crashes,
    // then the whole JVM will shut down.
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.
        UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                System.out.println(t + " throws exception: " + e);
                System.exit(1);
            }
        });

    // Do anything you want from here
    ....
}
```

This will start the shut down procedure of the JVM. Note that some active threads might still run for a while.